# SQL Query that rund monthly on a fixed day range

Tags: sql, date, variables, range, fixed

I have an SQL query I need to run once a month.

The data set the query produces always has to be from the 11th of the month before to the 10th of the current month.

I now manualy run the query in the fews days after the 11th day of the month manually adjusting the date range in my where statement:

for example...

Where Column A is greater than 10/10/2015 and less than 12/11/15

I was hoping there would be a statement I could add to my query to automatically find the 11th day of the last month and the 10th of the current month. This way I could schedule the query and automatically email the results.

Comment: What you need is an SQL Agent Job.

Comment: I thought about that but would still need script to set the date range for the query. simply running the query at a certain time still requires manually entering dates.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following within your query: -

```
CONVERT(date,FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM')+'-10')
```

(for the 10th of this month)

and

```
CONVERT(date,FORMAT(DATEADD(m,-1,GETDATE()),'yyyy-MM')+'-11')
```

(for the 11th of last month).

Answer (score -1):

Try to look out the MONTH() function in your working DBMS. In MySQL and MSSQL it returns a number (1 been january) corresponding to the current month that your system is (you may check if it's date is updated).

With this function you can subtract 1 to get the last month, having to do some logic when the current one is January, hence 1. Since now you should get 12 (december) intead of 0 (an error).

Cheers, mate!